# How to create shortcuts inside any application?

Tags: shortcut-keys

for example when I'm in Firefox I would like to press Alt+F and have sidebar opened (its in menu View -> Sidebar -> sidebar)

Is there any application that can do this?

P.S. I have used Firefox as example.

Answer (score 1):

These are application dependent and can be set at the application it self. If a application was not programmed to take shortcuts you cannot force it (easily) to do things with shortcuts.

Short answer: you cant, not unless the application is already programmed to have them.